# variable doesn't increase when code is executed

Tags: java

Tester is called and executed if the player inputs a certain name.

Variable testerWrong doesnt add one when **testerWrong++** is executed

```
private void Tester(){  

    int testerTotal;
    int testerScore;
    int testerWrong;
    testerTotal = 0;
    testerScore = 0;
    testerWrong = 0;

    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Hello tester, you're the designated tester. Would you like to take the quiz? Y/N");
    Scanner yesno = new Scanner(System.in);
    String YesNo = yesno.next();
    if(YesNo.equals("Y") || YesNo.equals("y")){                 //This type of code will appear very often
        System.out.println("Okay, let's being!");       //if the user input (YesNo) is Y or y then...
    }else{
        if(YesNo.equals("N") || YesNo.equals("n")){
            System.out.println("Okay, maybe some other time");
        }else{                                                  //else...
            System.out.println("Sorry, i do not recognise what you entered. Please restart the program.");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("");
    QUIZ enter = new QUIZ();
    enter.e2c();
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Question #1");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("The answer is A");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println(" - A. ");
    System.out.println(" - B. ");
    System.out.println(" - C. ");
    System.out.println(" - D. ");
    Scanner testerQ1 = new Scanner(System.in);      
    String TesterQ1 = testerQ1.next();
    if(TesterQ1.equals("A") || TesterQ1.equals("a")){
        testerScore++;
        System.out.println("Correct! You have answered " + testerScore + " correct and " + testerWrong + " incorrect!");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Next Question.");
        System.out.println("");
    }else{
        testerWrong++;
        System.out.println("Incorrect! You have answered " + testerScore + " correct and " + testerWrong + " incorrect!");
        System.out.println("");
    }
```

Is there a way to make the variable execute without having to add a system output before it?

Thanks

Comment: Please post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve --- we don't know how you initialize your variables and what else is going on.

Comment: Just to point out, you can omit the `System.out.println("")` calls to make a newline. Instead, just go on the previous string and add `\n`.

Comment: Probably because these are all local variables--along with your scanner, which will cause no end of problems.

Comment: I was kinda hoping to avoid that, but if that is the only work around then that'll do. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is not a minimal (way too many print statements) or even complete example (the QUIZ class is not included).

Narrowing your code down to a minimum example:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Tester {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int testerScore = 0;
        int testerWrong = 0;

        System.out.println("The answer is A");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String answer = scanner.next();
        if (answer.equals("A") || answer.equals("a")) {
            testerScore++;
            System.out.print("Correct!");
        }
        else {
            testerWrong++;
            System.out.println("Incorrect! ");
        }
        System.out.println(" You hve answered " + testerScore + 
            " correct and " + testerWrong + " incorrect!");
    }
}
```

This works for me. Compare your code against this and see what you are doing differently.

If you cannot find the problem that way, run your code in a debugger. Step through the program to see what it does when.

You may also want to follow Java naming conventions (variables start with lower case letters, classes start with upper case letters but aren't all upper case), to make it easier for others to read your code.

Comment: Thank you for your response. So it's better to have Classes rather than methods for each of the players (i.e. i have methods for player 1, player 2 etc.) and call the classes rather than the method? Should i remove the multiple answer questions and just check for correct/incorrect answers rather than display multiple answers?

Comment: @user7431342 That's a different question and depends on your actual program and what you want to do.